# Create part shipment and check if item has been shipped

Tags: orders, shipping, shipment

Is it possible in Magento to ship single items of an order independently of each other programatically?

For example, say i have an order with 5 order items and i want to ship only 1 of those how can this be done?

Additionally, i would like to determine if any of the single items has been shipped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

**Manually**

Go to the order, generate shipment, and then enter the # of qty/items to ship in that particular shipment.

[image]

The order will remain in Processing or your custom status until all items have been shipped before it will be marked as Completed.

**Programmatically**

```
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment(
    array(
      'order_item_id'=>1,
      'order_item_id'=>4,
      'order_item_id'=>2
    )
);
```

---

There are several ways to check if an item has been shipped

1) Look at the order item's `qty_shipped` value:

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
    echo $item->getQtyShipped();
}
```

2) Look at the order item status:

```
$item->getStatus();
```

To get more information on how a status is determined (it's not a stored value, it's derived) see this class:

https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php#L194

---

More reading about generating shipments programmatically:

[Programmatically Creating Shipments](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/programmatically-creating-shipments)

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake.  I would like to do this in code

Comment: I have updated the question to avoid any future confusion.  Sorry for that

Comment: See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Let's see how long it takes to flush out the downvoter. Care to explain? :)

Comment: @philwinkle I didn't got the screen which you answered in community edition, Am I doing anything wrong?