# Split Shipment at the time of shipment creation based on the product attribute in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, shipment

I am using magento 1. I want to split the shipment based on the product attribute.

```
i have followed the link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12741/auto-split-magento-shipments-based-on-maximum-weight
```

> This is working fine when i create the shipment manually from admin. 
>       But its not working when shipment is created via any third party module. Because when shipment create programmatically, it wont invokes the controller.
>
> So i have also tried with shipment create before event "sales_order_shipment_save_before", but that event also wont work as it falls under infinite loop because whenever i write the code to create the shipment it again calls the shipment create before event.
>
> ```
> Any suggestion for this ?
> ```